# What is the point of stars in Mario Kart 8?

Tags: mario-kart-8

Not that stars that you get at the end of the races. But you can get up to 6 stars (I believe) and they show up in the upper left portion of the screen. What do those do?

Comment: That's 'favoriting', and you can favorite a course by pressing the `+` button on the gamepad.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are used to mark 'favorites' in MKTV. If you completed a race that was particularly eventful that you want to save for later, mark it as a favorite by starring it at the end of the race. It makes it a lot easier to find the ones you want to keep, rather than going through all your recent races.

You can keep up to 6 favorite races at a time, and can edit or remove these favorites in MKTV.